# Mouse properties are corrupted

Tags: windows-7, mouse, cursor

In Windows 7, whenever I hover over things, the mouse automatically selects items or follows last item in the page without me clicking.

In mouse properties settings when I clicked Pointers option in mouse properties tab menu this error is shown:

> The C:\Windows\Cursors\Precisions Select.cur file, which contains the 'Precision Select' cursor, is either missing or corrupt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running sfc/ scannow command in CMD (with Administrative privileges). This would take some time but will fix the corrupted system file.

Comment: This problem is solved. In device manager settings there is an extra device in Mice and other pointing devices that always hover in last item. I disabled this device, so  the problem has gone.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try uninstalling all the drivers from mice and other pointing devices in the Device Manager.

   [image: Device Manager]

2. Then restart the PC.
3. Then go to windows Update and check for updates there you will have an update for your mouse driver.